# Why does pinterest set the height of an image instead of the width?

Tags: css, layout

I have been studying the page code of the Pinterest website lately to learn some design tricks in CSS. One thing I observed is that they set the height of each of their images using a CSS style. This is odd to me because it is clear that they are all being resized in order to have a uniform WIDTH of 192px. Is there a technical reason for setting the height instead of the width?

Example:

```
<img src="http://media-cache-ec8.pinterest.com/upload/30962316158222159_nQdVRIXP_b.jpg" alt="Summer camp" class="PinImageImg" style="height: 163px;">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pinterest uses a JQuery masonry. http://masonry.desandro.com/
Now, if you try using masonry for floating for objects as Pinterest does; there comes a point where your objects won't arrange no matter how much you zoom in or zoom it. If you play around by setting width for the objects; you'll soon realize the maths behind "Pinterest's 192px". After giving reasonable padding and margin, you'll HAVE to assign this particular width for the proper function of the arrangement. I've worked on a developing a website similar to Pinterest and it took us over a week to decrypt the logic behind "Pinterest's 192px width"

Comment: +1 for introducing me to masonry. Still though, my question is why they are setting the height property instead of the width. If the width is always 192, why bother calculating what the appropriate height is every time? Seems unnecessary but perhaps it is required by masonry?

Comment: Pinterest never calculates the height. It simply saves the image in 192px width and the height is dynamically taken care of. If you happen to see Pinterest's CSS code; it goes:
`element.style {
    height: 127px;//dynamic height calculated by Masonry, hence shown as **element.style**
}
.pin .ImgLink img {
    max-width: 192px; //main thing 
    opacity: 1;
}`
PS: I dont know if I'm able to explain you properly.

Comment: The HTML code that appears where you are seeing the height property is because of Masonry.

Comment: I too used masonry/isotope and I guess Pinterest when I redid my homepage. I also used SimplePie and PHP. I too settled on 192 pixels. The problem with 192 pixel images is they are too small to get Twitter Card with Large Image support. If I did things all over I'd use images over 200 pixels as Twitter is still more important than Pinterest at least to me.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about the technology I used when I redid my homepage. But can I include links in a comment?  http://blog.muschamp.ca/2013/09/22/redid-homepage/

Answer (score 0):

The "aspect ratio" of the images isn't always optimal. Sometimes when you resize to X height and Y width, the resulting image is wider or higher than expected depending on the width/height ratio. If you set a fixed height in css you make sure it will never be bigger than that (and your design wont "break")

Comment: So why not set a fixed width instead since all of the widths are exactly the same? Seems that would be a simpler way to accomplish the same thing. Is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: I don't use pinterest but as far as im concerned, i had to do the same thing with my images; since I dont control how wide or high they are. I usually use max-width or max-height to achieve a better look and to prevent images from breaking my design.